# How to convert seconds into (Year:Month:Day Hour:Minutes:Seconds) time?

Tags: c#, .net, time

What is the best way to convert seconds into (Year:Month:Day Hour:Minutes:Seconds) time?

Let's say I have 959040000 seconds (1 year 5 months), are there any specialized classes/techniques in .NET that would allow me to convert those 959040000 seconds into (Year:Month:Day Hour:Minutes:Seconds) like to DateTime or something?

Comment: Do you want to add them to a specific date? or create a timespan?

Comment: I want to convert Year:Month:Day Hour:Minutes:Seconds. Such as: 1 year: 5 month : 0 day 00:00:00 format

Comment: If you take, for example, Zdravko's answer, you'll have to concatenate that string together yourself.  Nothing will auto format it for you.

Comment: The problem is how long is a Month? If I run your program in Feburary with the value 2592000 do I get "1 Month, 2 Days", if I run your program again in December do I get "0 Months, 30 days"?

Answer (score 5):

use the TimeSpan class:

```
var ts = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 959040000);
int days = ts.Days;
int years = days / 365;
....
```

Comment: You'd be better off using the `TimeSpan.FromSeconds` factory method. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.fromseconds.aspx

Comment: There is not `Years` Property in `TimeSpan`

Comment: TimeSpan not provide month and year

Comment: sorry... you are right, no Months and Years but still the correct way to calc time spans

Comment: @ZdravkoDanev You can edit your answer and I will take my downvote.

Answer (score 3):

To tell the truth, you can't because it depends on the start date i.e. 30 days may be 1 month 1 day, or 1 month 2 days, or less than a month or 365 days will be less than a year if it's a leap year.

But, you can use:

```
TimeSpan diff = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(959040000);
string formatted = string.Format(
      CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
      "{0} years, {1} months, {2} days, {3} hours, {4} minutes, {5} seconds",
      diff.Days / 365,
      (diff.Days - (diff.Days / 365) * 365)/30,
      (diff.Days - (diff.Days / 365) * 365) - ((diff.Days - (diff.Days / 365) * 365) / 30)*30,
      diff.Hours,
      diff.Minutes,
      diff.Seconds);

Console.WriteLine(formatted);
```

Output is:

> 30, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0

If you enter `856044326` the output will be:

> 27, 1, 22, 22, 5, 26

Comment: I think: TimeSpan diff = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(9590450425);

Comment: @user3408674 Yes, it is same. I have changed my code, because it is more appropriate to use `FromSeconds`.

Answer (score -1):

Here is another trick.. you can also use time span

```
DateTime date, date2;
           date = date2 = DateTime.Now;
           date2= date2.AddSeconds(959040000);
           var totaldays = (date2 - date).TotalDays;
           var totalHours = (date2 - date).TotalHours;
           var Totalmin = (date2 - date).TotalMinutes;
           var years = totaldays / 365;
```